# How to add a C compiler within an android app?

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk, compiler-construction

I am working on an android project, where for one instance I need the user to enter their source code, and app should compile and show them output/errors if any. Is there a way to do that? Suggestion and hints are much appreciated

Comment: That's a super broad question, actually. If you want a single sentence answer (for which each aspect will sprawl into a bunch of further questions): You could package your app with libllvm + libclang, use that to compile to a statically linked native binary to an anonymous in-memory file (this will require patching libllvm and libclang to support output to predefined file descriptors, created using `memfd_create`), which then is executed (within a sandbox) by means of the Linux `fexecve` syscall.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.